# Is touching the Diviner necessary?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* episode *The Things We Bury*, we see Reinhardt expose a series of people to the Diviner/Obelisk.  When one specific person touches it,

> it doesn't kill them.

This is the unnamed character played by

> Dichen Lachman.

Later in the episode, it's revealed that they're seemingly immortal.  Did touching the Diviner cause this immortality, or did they already have it naturally?

Comment: I did my best to sensibly use spoiler tags.  LMK if I messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably an Inhuman ability. As far as I know, an Inhuman needs to be exposed to a Terrigen Mist to get their abilities, and the Terrigen Mist is produced by the Terrigen Crystals which are inside the Diviner. I don't think simply touching the Diviner will give you powers or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Since we do not have 100% confirmation in-universe at this time, my answer is based on informed speculation.

**Things we know for sure:**

- Skye's mother had the power of immortality and did not age
- Some people (Skye, Raina, Cal, Skye's mom) can touch the Diviner seemingly without being affected or turned into stone.

[image: no touching!]

- Neither Raina nor Skye were visibly transformed or granted powers by touching only the Diviner.
- The Diviner is actually a containment unit for what appears to be [Terrigen Crystals](http://marvel.wikia.com/Terrigen_Crystals).
- Upon opening the Diviner what appears to be [Terrigen Mists](http://marvel.wikia.com/Terrigen_Mist) are released. In the comics, Terrigen Mists are mutagenic vapors which cause transformation in Inhumans.

[image: dammit trip, I told you not to eat those beans]

- Upon contact with the mists, some people are transformed or granted powers.

[image: raina is going to have to shave more]

- At least some powers are transferable by surgical means.

**Things we don't know for sure:**

- Can/does a Diviner trigger non-visible changes in some people simply by touch? (e.g. Skye's mother's immortality)
- Did Skye's mother ever open a Diviner or otherwise be affected by Terrigen mists?
- Is there more than one temple? (Skye's mother was living in China, nowhere near the temple that we see.)
- Can a Diviner be opened without being placed in a temple?

**Conclusion**

Since Raina and Skye were not transformed simply by touching the Diviner, but *were* transformed by the Mists, I would speculate that **touching the Diviner is not necessary. The Mists are what affects people to grant them abilities/powers.**

Comment: Good call on the possible existence of another temple, especially since we know there is another Diviner out there ...